# Block change time privilege windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have been working on an application which runs a server on the local server.  We are using windows 7 on the server machine and the users need admin rights over the machine.  We are facing a problem w.r.t. the application if the system date and time are changed or the system time zone.  We have a lot of machines which are spread across the country, so can't use a policy as the time is very limited.  Is it possible to do with a batch file or an exe to block the admin to change time and timezone alone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Correct implementation would be to create a dedicated user with administrative rights but with some restrictions, and start the application under this user account, rather than give the user full administrative rights just to start your application.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp : I agree with you .. but as of now we can not revert the things what are already done in a short notice :)